# How to properly setup Catch2 tests in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, makefile, catch2

I'm trying to setup tests with Catch2 and setup a testing rule in a Makefile, it's a pre-requisite, I can't use CMake. I'm not sure how to go about that.

For example, I have something along those lines:

```
src
|
|--------- model
              |
              | 
              |-------- classA.hpp
              |-------- classA.cpp
              |-------- classB.hpp
              |-------- classB.cpp

tests/
|
|-------- catch.hpp
|-------- test-main.cpp
|-------- test_classA.cpp
|-------- test_classB.cpp
```

I'd like to have Makefile rules for a `test` target to run all the tests. Reading a [practical example](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/v2.x/docs/slow-compiles.md#practical-example) from the Catch docs was helpful to setup the files but I'm a bit lost about what to afterwards. `test-main` uses an hyphen an not an underscore, to avoid the wildcard later (since it's compiled only once).

For now, my (simplified) Makefile is along those lines:

```
testdir := tests
test_sources := $(wildcard $(testdir)/test_*.cpp)
```

Then, this is where the example confuses me, it seems I need to compile `test-main.cpp`, my classes in the model directory AND add the test sources files during the creation of the test executable.

This is what is said in the above example in Catch's README.

[image: [See this example from the docs](https://imgur.com/a/QkLd5DH).]

I just don't know how to create Makefile rules that will allow me to do that and I can't seem to find an example online with many test files.

Thanks for the help.